# Parsing "0x0" as two numbers using sscanf

Tags: c, scanf

I made a general purpose function for parsing the values written in a configuration string as doubles. When there are two values to be read the function that parses the line of text containing those two values is provided a delimiting string `delim_str` to know what separates the two values. I do the parsing by first creating the format string `fmt` by doing `sprintf(fmt, "%%lg%s%%lg", delim_str);`, then I use it for parsing by doing `sscanf(input_string, fmt, &v1, &v2);`.

Everything is fine when I use a `delim_str` such as `" - "` or `", "`, the problem occurs when I use it to parse screen resolutions using `"x"` as a delimiter, it parses input strings like `1920x1080` into two values fine, but if the first value is 0 then `0x1080` gives me a `v1` value of 4224 (0x1080 interpreted as an hexadecimal value) instead of 0 and `v2` isn't modified.

I can think of using `strstr` to find the start of `delim_str` inside the input string, then use that to create two new strings, one for each variable, but I have a feeling that there must be a more elegant approach.

Comment: you can use `strtok` if you want.

Comment: Why are you using `%lg` to parse integers instead of `%d`?

Comment: Also note that `%i` will scan hexadecimal and octal numbers but `%d` does not.

Comment: @melpomene oh right maybe I should have mentioned, it's pretty general purpose so I didn't make separate functions for parsing doubles and ints, so I use doubles as a common denominator for all numbers. So the function reads and returns doubles, but the caller function is free to cast them. There's not much downside to that as long as the integer numbers are below something like 2^52.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `x` as a delimiter for your floating point numbers, you cannot parse the string with `%g` or `%lg`: the conversion specifiers for floating point numbers parse the input as `strtod()` would and `strtod` accepts the hexadecimal float syntax since c99:

> **7.22.1.3 The strtod, strtof, and strtold functions**
>
> ...
>
> The expected form of the subject sequence is an optional plus or minus sign, then one of the following:
>
> — a nonempty sequence of decimal digits optionally containing a decimal-point character, then an optional exponent part as defined in 6.4.4.2;
>
> — a `0x` or `0X`, then a nonempty sequence of hexadecimal digits optionally containing a decimal- point character, then an optional binary exponent part as defined in 6.4.4.2;
>
> — `INF` or `INFINITY`, ignoring case
>
> — `NAN` or `NAN(`n-char-sequenceopt`)`, ignoring case in the `NAN` part...

This is a semantic change from previous versions of the C Standard, causing input such as `0x0` to be parsed as a single floating point value.

The simplest solution is to use `%d` to parse the numbers into `int` variables. if they are integers and reasonably small. Note however that composing the format string with `sprintf` is risky:

- if the `delim_str` is too long, `sprintf` may cause a buffer overrun. You should use `snprintf()` instead
- if the `delim_str` contains embedded `%` characters, the resulting format string may cause undefined behavior when passed to `scanf()`.

A safer approach would use `strstr` to locate the delimiter string in the input and split the input into substrings passed to `strtod()`.

Here is an example:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char input[] = "0x1080";
    const char *delim_str = "x";
    char *p;
    double v1 = 0;
    double v2 = 0;

    if ((p = strstr(input, delim_str)) != NULL) {
        *p = '\0';
        v1 = strtod(input, NULL);
        *p = *delim_str;
        v2 = strtod(p + strlen(delim_str), NULL);
        printf("%g %g\n", v1, v2);
    } else {
        printf("missing delimiter: %s\n", input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If the `input` string cannot be modified, a copy of the initial part must be made.

Comment: I like that you didn't use `strtok` as I don't like to make my code become non-reentrant for no reason.

Comment: @MichelRouzic Also note that `strtok_r` could be used.

Comment: @JL2210: `strtok_r` could be used, but its semantics are confusing for anything but white space. `strstr` is more precise and can be used with any string for an exact match. Using `strtok_r` with `", "` would detect any sequence of consecutive `' '` or `','` characters as a single separator.

Comment: `strtok_r` is a POSIX function, not standard C.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a strtok/strtod combination: `strtok` to get two strings and then `strtod` to convert it to the desired double format.

It could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char input_string[] = "0x1080";
    char delim_str[] = "x";


    char *v1str = NULL;
    char *v2str = NULL;

    v1str = strtok(input_string, delim_str);
    if(v1str != NULL) {
        v2str = strtok(NULL, delim_str);
    }

    if(!v1str || !v2str) {
        fprintf(stderr, "format error");
        exit(1);
    }

    double v1 = strtod(v1str, NULL);
    double v2 = strtod(v2str, NULL);
    printf("%f %f", v1, v2);


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered that I already have a function in my library that could be used to isolate the substrings, although as a general answer it's a bit overkill since this specific problem can be solved with less code. It looks for the Nth field in a string according to a given delimiter:

```
int string_get_field(char *string, char *delim, int n, char *field) // copies the Nth field (0 indexed) of string into field
{
    int i;
    size_t delim_len = strlen(delim);
    char *end;

    // Find field start
    for (i=0; i < n; i++)
    {
        string = strstr(string, delim);         // look for the next delimiter

        if (string==NULL)               // if the next delimiter needed isn't found
            return 0;               // 0 means failure to find the field

        string += delim_len;                // set string to right after the delimiter that indicates the start
    }

    // Find field end
    end = strstr(string, delim);                // look for the next delimiter that marks the end of the field

    // Copy field
    if (end==NULL)                      // if it was the last field
        strcpy(field, string);              // copy all that is left
    else                            // otherwise
    {
        snprintf(field, end-string, "%s", string);  // only copy what's in the field
        field[end-string] = 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The string `field` should obviously be large enough, even as large as `string` to be safe. We could parse it like this:

```
char *field = calloc(strlen(input_string)+1, sizeof(char));

if (string_get_field(input_string, delim_str, 0, field))
    v1 = strtod(field, NULL);

if (string_get_field(input_string, delim_str, 1, field))
    v2 = strtod(field, NULL);

free(field);
```